# Constructor Inject with Ninject 2

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I've used Ninject with MVC3 for automagic inject of constructor arguments.  It worked great.

How do you do something similar with non-MVC code.

For example:

```
public class Ninja
{
    private readonly IWeapon _weapon;
    public Ninja(IWeapon weapon)
    {
        _weapon = weapon;
    }

    public void Strike()
    {
        _weapon.Strike();
    }
}


public class MyProgram
{
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        var Ninja = new Ninja(); // I'm wanting Ninject to call the parameterized Ninja constructor
        ninja.Strike();
    }

}
```

How would I alter the code to get it to work?

Answer (score 5):

```
public interface IWeapon
{
    void Strike();
}

public class Sword : IWeapon
{
    public void Strike()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("black ninja strike");
    }
}

public class Ninja
{
    private readonly IWeapon _weapon;
    public Ninja(IWeapon weapon)
    {
        _weapon = weapon;
    }

    public void Strike()
    {
        _weapon.Strike();
    }
}

public class WarriorModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>();
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel(new WarriorModule());
        var ninja = kernel.Get<Ninja>();
        ninja.Strike();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn't it just be:

```
var ninja = Kernel.Get<Ninja>();
```

You obviously have to resolve the dependency though Ninject.

Comment: Is there a global for the current Kernel?

Comment: @Adam Tegen: thankfully no. Have a search for Service Locator antipattern and go read @Mark Seemann's top-votes answers for the why. (Some Ninject extensions do have a KernelContainer object, but that's only on an as-needed-basis and definitely not a core feature)

Comment: For ASP.NET you might be right. For MVVM, I think I need to a talk with Mark about it. Also, performance can also sometimes justify the use of antipatterns.

Comment: Also, I think you meant this article: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an instance of `StandardKernel` let's call it `kernel` and then use `kernel.Get<Ninja>()`. This works since Ninja is non abstract, so it is considered bound to itself. Obviously some concrete types needs to be bound to IWeapon to allow NInject to create Ninja.